# Are questions about on-topic organizations or outlets related to on-topic properties on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Sorry, I know that question is difficult to follow.

The specific case I'm asking about would be about the history of the leadership (editting, hosting, and ownership) of the [Escape Pod podcast](http://escapepod.org/).   For those not familiar this is a [long-running](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Escape_Pod_episodes) podcast that pays for and publishes audio versions of high-quality SF short stories by a wide variety of authors.

This has evolved many times over the over-a-decade run, and I've never been able to identify when changeovers occurred and why.   Usually there is a little blurb within a podcast that mentions the change, but it's obviously not practical to go listen to the beginning and end of every podcast to determine the history.

An equivalent question might be something like:

> What is the history of the leadership and ownership of DC Comics?

## On-topic?   If not, why not?

Answer (score 4):

That just sounds like 'behind the scenes and fandom information', which is on topic.

Comment: Well, the reason to be concerned would be that Escape Pod is an outlet, not a content property.   But if it's okay, it's okay.

Comment: fundamentally, i'd agree that this sounds like behind the scenes/fandom, but i'd also note that the example question provided feels way too broad.

Comment: @phantom42:  The DC Comics example?   Why too broad?   Just because it is such a complex organization with many different arms and properties over too much time?

Comment: @phantom42 Good point. On topic doesn't necessarily mean that it's a suitable question.

Comment: @ThePopMachine yes. historically on SE (not here, specifically), the general guideline was that if you could write an entire article or wikipedia page on it, it's probably too broad.

Comment: `There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.`

Comment: @phantom42:   OK -- just clarifying that your opinion was based on DC Comics being too complex.